# Border not appearing in IE9 & IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I am having an issue with a table border not displaying correctly. Below is a fiddle recreating the issue.

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVDm2/20/) produces expected results in FF and Chrome but not in IE9 and IE10.

Only css that is being applied is a border-collapse: collapse and

```
td{
   border:1px solid;
}
```

The second table row should have a border along the entire bottom however the border is missing on the second table cell. Can be seen in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WppJo.jpg).

This issue disappears once part of the table is highlighted but the expected result is that the border should be there in the first place. Sometimes the fiddle must be updated for the issue to appear.

Is this a known IE issue or is there more styling that must be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution that I could find:

```
table{border-top:1px solid #000;}
tr{border-left:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
td{border-right:1px solid #000;}
```

[Example here](http://dev.bescow.com/ieborder/)

Checked in both IE9 and IE10

Comment: If you make the edit in JSFiddle it will solve the issue initially. 

However, upon selecting "Update" the issue will return. 

It seems like some interaction (highlighting, changing in JSFiddle, inspecting with developer tools) with the table will cause it to render the border correctly, however it doesn't render on initial page load.

Comment: humm... Yes, it's very strange...
Updated answer

Comment: This fixed my issue.
Needed minor modifications to work on my application (there was a global css style on the td which had to be overwritten with border-bottom-style: none).
Thank you.

Comment: @PavloShandro This shouldn't work. At least in my tests, putting borders on TR elements with CSS doesn't show in IE10, so the table explained above will not have a left nor bottom border.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and your solution above worked for me with a slight change. (I used primefaces)

Following code worked

```
.ui-datatable tbody>tr>td {
    border-top: 1.1px solid; 
}
```

Following code didn't work

```
.ui-datatable tbody>tr>td {
    border-top: 1px solid; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is caused by `border-collapse: collapse` it can also be solved by placing the borders in the correct places manually and using `border-collapse: separate`.

```
table { 
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
    border-bottom:1px solid;
    border-right:1px solid;
}

tr > td:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid;
}

table tr:first-child td {
    border-top: 1px solid;
}
```

This doesn't work in IE7 and below because they don't support neither `border-spacing` nor `:first-child`.

Comment: In IE11, border-collapse: separate and border-spacing: 0 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c674a015-11cb-49af-a876-887fe7900d89/ie9-css-table-with-bordercollapse-fails-to-render-some-borders-when-printing?forum=iewebdevelopment) worked:

```
<table cellspacing="0" and cellpadding="0"> ... </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found using `position: static;` on the `th`/`td` works well.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
}
tr {
    border: none;
}
th, td {
    position: static;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```